# ZSH prompt displaying ~window_label instead of folder name

Tags: git, command-line, zsh, prompt

Somehow my zsh prompt is showing the text **~window_label** in certain folders rather than showing its name. Seems to be an issue with the git folders, but some git folders shows up correctly.

Following is the zsh theme I use.

```
PROMPT='%{$reset_color%}[%{$fg[cyan]%}%2~%{$fg_bold[blue]%}$(git_prompt_info)%{$fg_bold[blue]%}%{$reset_color%}] $ '
# PROMPT='[%{$fg_bold[blue]%}%2~ $(git_prompt_info)%{$reset_color%}%(!.#.$) ] $ '


ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_PREFIX="%{$reset_color%} | %{$fg[blue]%}git:‚Äπ%{$fg[red]%}"
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_SUFFIX="%{$reset_color%}"
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_DIRTY="%{$fg[blue]%}‚Ä∫%{$fg[yellow]%}‚úó%{$reset_color%}"
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_CLEAN="%{$fg[blue]%}‚Ä∫"
```

Answer (score 1):

The `%2~` in your prompt is responsible for this behaviour. Usually this gets replaced by the last two components of the current working directory. But when the current working directory has a named directory as prefix, this part is replaced by `~` followed by the name of the directory or just `~` in the case of `$HOME`.

Typically named directories are the home directories, but others can be defined. In your case it seems to be a *static named directory*, which can be defined by either setting a shell parameter with a value starting with `/`

```
window_label=/some/path/to/somewhere
```

or by using `hash -d`

```
hash -d window_label=/some/path/to/somewhere
```

Either way, instead of `/some/path/to/somewhere` your prompt will show `~window_label`.

Going from the name of the parameter `window_label` it is probably set for the title of the terminal window. That may also be the cause why it happens only for some git folders: the directory name representation (`~window_label`) is only used if it is the shortest way of representing the current directory. For example: `/tmp/foo` would not be replaced, while `/tmp/foo/bar/baz` would.

For more information have a look at the section *"Filename Expansion"*, especially subsection *"Static Named directories"* in *zshmisc(1)*.